# cordova - angualrjs - <a> inside html, how to preventDefault if ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I have a Cordova app, thats getting an html text from an json api. The problem is that inside that text i have  links, and if you press on them it opens them up inside the cordova webview.
Example text from json call:

```
{newstext: "<div>
       Some text
       <div>
         Some text 2
         <a href="www.google.com">Go link</a>
      </div>
     </div>"
}
```

I need to somehow parse it or intercept it. I tried the e.preventDefaults, even tried to add a custom class, but it does not find the links if its like this on the angularjs template:

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlText"></div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do that, but this should do the trick.

`<a href="SOME_URL" ng-click="$event.preventDefault()">`

You can either remove `href` attribute from `<a>` tags. See [ngHref docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHref) examples.

Comment: The problem is that i call an external service, that returns a json with: { newstext: "...the..html..text" }. I cant check if every newstext contains a href and fix it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to block this links you can use cordova/phonegap [domain whitelist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html).

If you need to filter the server responses you can do it with an interceptor.

```
app.config(function($provide, $httpProvider){
    $provide.factory('FilterInterceptor', function($q, $injector, $window, $rootScope){
    return {

        request: function(config){
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },

        requestError: function(rejecton){
            return $q.reject(rejecton);
        },

        response: function(response){
            //Check if your calling an external URL
            if(new RegExp("externalresource").test(response.config.url)) {
                console.log(response.data);
                //Do a substitution on the href with navigator.load(url, openexternal:true) 
            }

            return response  || $q.when(response);
        },

        responseError: function(rejecton){
            return $q.reject(rejecton);
        }
    }});
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('FilterInterceptor');
});
```

Just be sure to do the substitution of the `href` attribute only on the calls on the external resource.

Comment: Dont want to block, just open the link in external mode, i need to somehow parse the html string that i recive and replace a hrefs with e.g.: navigator.load(url, openexternal:true)

Comment: Hmm. the response fires when i enter the page, the controller runs its $http call to get the json object containg newsText, but if i click a link inside the newsText html this does not fire, or did i missunderstand.

Comment: With this interceptor you can parse and modify the response you get from the `$http` call and remove all the `href`.

Comment: Another way would be to use [`transformResponse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses) instead of checking every $http call.